# Convert NSData to an Array of JSON objects

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

I am accessing a HTTP GET method in my swift code. this method is returning an NSData variable. This data is essentially just an array of json objects, like so:

```
[{"author": "meowmeow", "platform": "Google"}, {"author": "adasd", "platform": "Dropbox"}
```

and is stored in the variable data.

I want to cast this NSData variable into an array of json objects I can easily access but just can't figure out how to do this with swifty json.

I have tried the following:

```
let jsonString = NSString(data: data! as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

But when I do this after:

```
 var jj = JSON.init(parseJson: jsonString!)
        for j in jj {
            print(j)
            print("------")
}
```

Nothing is printed, implying the JSON.init method is not succesfully parsing the string and returning an Array that can be looped through. How can I cast the NSData into an array of JSON objects i can access like:

```
print(jj[0]["author"])
```

Comment: are you using Swift or Objective-C? NSURLSession API in swift returns Data not NSData

Comment: post your networking request code in description

Comment: Why `NSString` and `NSData` in Swift? Don't do that. The same code in native Swift is dramatically shorter (and more efficient): `let jsonString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SwiftyJSON [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) page

```
let json = JSON(data: data) //use this method
for dict in json {
  //do the stuff
}
```